# How not to make an API call if the store already contains data in react-redux

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

I'm trying to make an API call using axios and storing data in redux store.
My current situation is that if I let's say go from PageA (where PageA is making an API call) to PageB (it also makes an API call), and I return back to PageA, it again makes an API call,  and I need to prevent it since I know data is already present in redux store.

reducer:

```
const initialState = {
    idx : 0
};
export const getData = (args) => ({ type: "GET_DATA", args });
export const setData = (someContent) => ({ type : "SET_DATA", someContent });

export default function myReducer(state = initialState, action){
    switch (action.type){
        case "SET_DATA":
            const {data} = action;
            return {...state, data};
        default:
            return state;
    }
}
```

handler:

```
// .. imports
export function* handleGetData(action){
  try{
      const response = yield call(requestGetData,action);
      const {data} = response;
      yield put(setData(data));
  }
  catch(error){
      console.log(error);
  }
}
```

request:

```
export async function requestGetData(action){
    const url = `http://localhost:8080/`
    try {
        return await axios.request({
            method: 'get',
            url,
        });
    } 
    catch (err) { console.log(err.message);}
}
```

store:

```
import { combineReducers, createStore, applyMiddleware } from "redux";
import createSagaMiddleware from "@redux-saga/core";
import {watcherSaga} from "../sagas/sagaRoot";

import myReducer from "../reducers/reducerFile";

const reducer = combineReducers({
    pageA: myReducer
});

const sagaMiddleWare = createSagaMiddleware();
const middleWare = [sagaMiddleWare];

const  store = createStore(reducer,{},applyMiddleware(...middleWare));

sagaMiddleWare.run(watcherSaga);
export default store;
```

PageA:

```
  // stuff
  const dispatch = useDispatch();

  const rows = useSelector(state=> state.pageA.someContent);
  
  useEffect(()=>{
    if(!rows){
      dispatch(getData());
    }
  },[dispatch, rows])
```

Currently I'm doing this ^ in order to ensure that if there's no data then only make the call.

What's the efficient way to check whether the store contains data for the reducer or not, in order to prevent API calls.

Comment: It looks you are losing your state when jumps to another page and turn back to previous. If you want keep data across pages redux-persist is what you're looking for. In my opinion the way used by you to check state with useEffect looks fine

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I will definitely explore redux persist

Comment: For your problem I usually store a 'loaded' boolean in the reducer next to the data entry and use it to decide whether or not I should reload.

Comment: Its can be a nice strategy only you need know if some data was loaded somewhere in time. But into my projects if I ask to reducer hey do you have some data? That's because I want consome it for something such as present something to end-user. If data is no longer necessary I perform cleanup at component onload